# Stop layout expanding beyond 940px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to stop the layout from expanding beyond 940px?

I have certain elements that mess up beyond 940px. I still need the layout to be responsive for mobile, just anything device bigger than 940px doesn't need bigger items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the [CSS/Properties/max-width](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/max-width)

```
body {
   max-width: 940px;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing margin: 0 auto; is also needed because when adding max-width to body it's no longer centered.

Comment: adding max-width to the container works, and keeps it centered.

Answer (score 0):

would need to see your code, however setting `max-width:940px;` to the element will do it.

This will prevent it from expanding past 940 but still be responsive for mobile.